# Why must I specify context_object_name in my DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django (using version 1.5.1), recently completed the official Django tutorial. Now I'm making my own little app, and encountered something that I can't figure out.

I have a DetailView generic view, and have set the attribute `model = Transaction`. In my template, I can access fields on the model with `{{ object.payee }}`. However, I can't use `{{ Transaction.payee }}` unless I set `context_object_name = 'Transaction'` in my view.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name), it looks like this should work, and it worked fine in the official tutorial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us the views.py please

Comment: What about {{ transaction.payee }}?

Comment: @garnertb you are correct - the template is case sensitive. Thank you.

Comment: and I should add - though the class name is Transaction (Titlecase), the template object name is transaction (lowercase).

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs you linked:

> For example, the model Article would have context object named 'article'

So, for `Transaction`, the context object would be named `transaction`.